# use html in primeng p-toast

Tags: angular, primeng, toast

I would like to use html code 
 in primeng toast module.
I have tried different options but cannot get it to work.

```
this.messageService.add({ sticky: true, severity: 'error', summary: 'Import job', detail: 'first line of text <br\>second line of text'});
```

anyone suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually you can with a little tick in CSS, declaring this in your main sylesheet:

```
.ui-toast-detail {
   white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Now yours `\n` will work in the message :)

Comment: For v12 at least, the class that needs to receive this style is `p-toast-detail`. Changing the class name makes this fix work perfectly.

Answer (score 14):

In order to use an HTML content in the `p-toast`, you can use a very simple custom message template.

```
<p-toast position="top-center">
    <ng-template let-message pTemplate="message">
        <p innerHtml="{{message.detail}}"></p>
    </ng-template>
</p-toast>
```

No extra variable needed, the template uses the message variable which is native to the Primeng component.

Comment: Did anyone get this working with a routerlink in Angular?

Comment: The original template, which also shows summary and icons, can be found [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/toast/toast.ts).

Answer (score 6):

make variable to bind your data in it and when call your function call it like this and make sure that detail is empty

```
descreption : string = '';

showInfo(descreption) {
  this.descreption = descreption;
  this.messageService.add({severity: 'info', summary: 'samary', detail:''});
}
```

and in html use ng-template and bind your data using innerHtml and pass your variable like this

```
  <p-toast [style]="{marginTop: '80px'}" styleClass="custom-toast">
      <ng-template let-message pTemplate="message">
        <div style="text-align: center">
          <p  innerHtml="{{descreption}}"></p>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
  </p-toast>
```

Comment: For me it works just with: 
<p-toast>
      <ng-template let-message pTemplate="message">
          <p  innerHtml="{{message.details}}"></p> <!-- .details in my particular case-->
      </ng-template>
  </p-toast>

Comment: AMAZING !!  This worked perfectly, and exactly what I wanted, as I was displaying notifications from an app-wide service, so couldn't bind to an Angular variable.

Answer (score 5):

You can make it add in the html definition the following:

```
<p-toast [style]="{'white-space': 'pre-line'}" ></p-toast>
```

and in the component you can try it with the following code:

```
let arrays: string[] = ['first line', 'second line'];
    this.messageService.add({ summary: 'Title',  detail:  arrays.join('\n'), severity: 'warn', sticky: true });
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use HTML in the detail of the MessageService because it will not render the HTML.  Your only option if you want multiple lines, is to utilize the ng-template to build your dialog how you want.

Comment: I thought the same thing... but it's not true.  See Ayman's solution below.

Comment: @MikeGledhill it's above now :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<p-toast>
  <ng-template let-message pTemplate="message">
    <div style="flex: 1" [innerHtml]="message.detail"></div>
  </ng-template>
</p-toast>
```

Using this option, you can insert any HTML without breaking any design issues of close button.